# Tuning down TimescaleDB continuous aggregate logging

Tags: timescaledb

I am extensively using TimescaleDB continuous aggregate jobs.

Currently, my PostgreSQL log is populated with lines like:

```
2021-12-02 17:24:56.273 UTC [18963] LOG:  refreshing continuous aggregate "candle_ohlcvx_aggregate_5m" in window [ 2021-11-29 17:25:00, 2021-12-02 17:20:00 ]
```

This is because there is a log every time a job runs and I have jobs running every minute.

Is there a way to tune down refreshing continuous aggregate logging so that PostgreSQL log would not be unnecessarily bloated with these messages?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, it will log always accordingly to the code: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/blob/5eadbbd0978fa327b57a9e91b3b321ca0b48c053/tsl/src/continuous_aggs/refresh.c#L713 Maybe you can configure your log levels to be higher?

Comment: Ok - I will open an issue.